# MongoDB .NET Driver - Update Item in Set

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-update

I've got this entity:

```cs
internal record OrderBookEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    public required AssetDefinition UnderlyingAsset { get; init; }
    
    public required List<OrderEntity> Orders { get; init; }
}
```

which leads to this sort of document:

```
{
    _id: {
        Class: 0,
        Symbol: 'EURUSD'
    },
    Orders: [
        {
            _id: 'a611ffb1-c3e7-43d6-8238-14e311122125',
            Price: '-10.000000101',
            Amount: '30.000000003',
            OrderAction: 1,
            EffectiveTime: ISODate('2022-10-14T06:33:02.872Z')
        },
        {
            _id: 'a611ffb1-c3e7-43d6-8238-14e311122126',
            Price: '-10.000000101',
            Amount: '30.000000003',
            OrderAction: 1,
            EffectiveTime: ISODate('2022-10-14T06:33:08.264Z')
        }
    ]
}
```

I can add and remove from the `Orders` set without updating the whole document with:

```cs
Builders<OrderBookEntity>.Update.AddToSet(...);
Builders<OrderBookEntity>.Update.Pull(...);
```

I can't, however, see a way to modify one of those in place.

How would I go about changing the `Amount` on saying `a611ffb1-c3e7-43d6-8238-14e311122125` without having to read the document, modify the collection, and update the whole thing, or just pulling and reading the order... Neither of which seems particularly performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with `FieldDefinition` by providing the field to be updated in string instead of Func expression.

> MongoDB query

```
db.collection.update({
  "Orders._id": "a611ffb1-c3e7-43d6-8238-14e311122125"
},
{
  $set: {
    "Orders.$.Amount": "100"
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cxkE3Hqj43F)

> MongoDB .NET Driver syntax

```cs
var filter = new BsonDocument 
{ 
    { "Orders._id", "a611ffb1-c3e7-43d6-8238-14e311122125" } 
};
var update = Builders<OrderBookEntity>.Update.Set("Orders.$.Amount", /* value */);

UpdateResult result = await _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

> Demo

[image]